# How can I set the origin of the html5 canvas in the bottom-left corner

Tags: html, canvas

I want to set the origin of my canvas in the bottom left corner like in a classic (O, x, y )  Cartesian landmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming the `canvas` context is equivalent to changing the origin.

```
<canvas width="100" height="100" id="mycanvas"></canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 0);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100,100);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/DZqV5/).

Comment: This only works for symmetrical operations like lines or rects. If you attempt to draw text you'll see the transform correctly applies to that as well which may not be what you want.